# how to determine the number of rows allowed to enter from form using oracle forms 6i?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

using database: oracle database 11.2

using form builder: oracle forms builder 6i

I have a screen which builded in oracle forms 6i, where the end user can enter data. This screen deals with only one table in the database. I want to set a certain number of lines in the table if it reaches that number the end user cannot enter other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a strange requirement ...

Anyway, you could create a `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` block-level trigger and put this in there:

```
if :system.trigger_record = 10 then             --> 10 represents limit
   message('You can not enter any more rows');
   raise form_trigger_failure;
end if;
```

Comment: its not a strange requirement but that data should be limited to activation code. thanks for you answer. i will try it right now.

Comment: its not working, the message appears that i cant add more recods but i can i just press the add button and enter all data and save.

Comment: i did it in another way... by remove Menu Module...  and i make my personal buttons  add, delete, update and search and then edited your code a little bit by adding `set_item_property('block.button', enabled, property_false);`

Comment: thank you @Littlefoot i see your answers many times with others posts... you helped so much peoples thank you dear.